# Интеграция плагина в WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Использую много JS. Локально все работает, но когда пытаюсь запустить на рабочем сайте - весь функционал убивается. У человека там висит куча JS кода, который возможно конфликтует с моим. Вот пример :

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(document).ready(function() 
   {
     jQuery("#tabs_b").tabs();
     var drawingMode = false;
     var selectedObject;
     var p_el = document.getElementById('c');
     var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(p_el);
```

Табы не  работают. Можно как-то изолировать свой код от всего мусора что висит на странице? пытаюсь запустить создание табов в консоли.
вроде все без ошибок, но табы так и не создаются. 
[image: Вот такая картинка в отладчике]

Что вообще делать в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Первое, что обращает на себя внимание, это слишком простые id в разметке. В приведенном примере кода Вы работаете с даже с однобуквенным id. Речь идёт даже не столько об информативности кода, сколько о вероятности возникновения конфликтов. Вы пробовали просмотреть полный код той страницы, на которой возникает конфликт?

Comment: конечно. однобуквенных id больше нет.) в основном классы. вы хотите сказать что  jQuery("#tabs_b").tabs();  - вот это не работает из за id? Что именно может здесь мешать? Другого элемента с таким id на странице нет

Comment: Пройдитесь по коду на "рабочем" сайте с отладчиком. JS - не ассемблер все же. Найти проблемные места вполне выполнимая задача

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос необднозначен, однако частично отвечу: чтобы изолировать свой код от глобальной области видимости можно обернуть его в анонимную функцию и сразу же ее вызвать

```
(function () { // анонимная функция (оборачиваем ее в скобки, чтобы можно были вызвать сразу

    // тут весь ваш код, включая функции

}()); // сразу вызываем
```

Comment: в моем случае я использую :  jQuery( document ).ready(function ()  {....}();  Я отключил часть ненужных  плагинов на сайте и все стало работать.

Comment: @coderisimo я рад за вас )

Comment: спасибо , там еще куча работы ))